# Is it possible to have a 2D scatter plot with circumference in 3D?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a scatter plot with each point having a circumference. I tried to plot the scatter points in 3D but couldn't get the circumference to plot.
Is it possible to convert this 2D plot to a 3D plot while having the circumference?

The sample code is in 2D

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Initialising random points for the users
x = np.arange(0,10)
y = np.random.randint(0,50, size=10)


ax = plt.subplot()
# Plot labels and plot type
# plt.scatter(x, y, color='b', marker='^')
ax.scatter(x, y, color='b')
# plt.xlabel("x")
# plt.ylabel("y")

# User Coordinates
coordinates = []
for i, j in zip(x, y):
    coordinates.append((i,j))




# Circumference Test
for a, b in coordinates:
    cir = plt.Circle((a,b), 1.5, color='r', 
    fill=False)
    ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='datalim')
    ax.add_patch(cir)


# Show Plot
# plt.grid(True)
fig1 = plt.gcf()
plt.savefig('Users.png')
plt.show()
```

Here is a 3D plot I tried using the mpl3d toolkit but the circumferences are all in the wring place and not in line with the plot points.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d as art3d

# Initialising random points for the users
x = np.random.randint(0, 40, size=10)
y = np.random.randint(0, 40, size=10)
z = np.random.randint(0, 40, size=10)

ax = plt.subplot(projection='3d')
# Plot labels and plot type
# plt.scatter(x, y, color='b', marker='^')
ax.scatter(x, y, z, color='b')
# plt.xlabel("x")
# plt.ylabel("y")

# User Coordinates
coordinates = []
for i, j, k in zip(x, y, z):
    coordinates.append((i, j, k))


# Circumference Test
for a, b, c in coordinates:
   cir = plt.Circle((a, b), 1.5, color='r', fill=False)
   # ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='datalim')
   ax.add_patch(cir)
   art3d.pathpatch_2d_to_3d(cir, z = c, zdir="x")

# Show Plot
# plt.grid(True)
fig1 = plt.gcf()
plt.savefig('Users.png')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you used to create the 3D plot which is not working? I think it will be easier to help you starting from there

Comment: @Andrea It was the same as this one just with another added axis in all the for loops, I thought that if I add another axis to the circumference loops it would work

Comment: To align them I think `art3d.pathpatch_2d_to_3d(cir, z = c, zdir="z")` should work. But since the circle will be drawn in the x-y plane, the projection will look elliptic

Comment: @Andrea yeah, i think i got it.  https://imgur.com/mGo7yc4 Thanks for the help